# How can I detect an external link with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple function

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $('.playthis').trigger('click');
},10);
```

Inside my website the navigation is made with Ajax, I need to trigger this function only if the user comes from outside not from Ajax. Is it possible?

I tried this

```
var ref = document.referrer;
if (ref.match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?example\.com(\/|$)/i)) {
  //nothing
} else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.playthis').trigger('click');
    },10);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's short example using `location.hostname` vs `document.referrer.split("/")[2]`

**Note**: snippet is running in iframe so it will alert `External referrer`

```js
    var isExternal = document.referrer.split("/")[2] !== location.hostname;

    if (isExternal) {
      alert("External referrer");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, before I wrongly used it inside `$(function() {`

Comment: Glad to help you :)